# How do I get a selected string in from a Tkinter text box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to be able to get a string out of a highlighted portion of text, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For a `Tkinter.Text` or `Tkinter.Entry` widget, you can use:

```
content = text.selection_get()
```

Interactive example of getting selected text both from an Entry and from a Text widgets in the Python console:

```
>>> import Tkinter
>>> w = Tkinter.Tk()
>>> e = Tkinter.Entry(w)
>>> e.pack()
>>> t = Tkinter.Text(w)
>>> t.pack()
#(scribble at the widgets in the created window, and select text in the Entry)
>>> e.selection_get()
'1234'
#(select text)
>>> t.selection_get()
'1234'
>>>
```

According to Bryan Oakley's comment:

> `selection_get` is a generic widget method available to all widgets. It does **not always** get the selected string from a Text widget. It might, but it's not guaranteed. What it does is get what's called the "X" selection (from tk's X11 roots). If you set `exportselection` to False for the Text widget, `selection_get` will fail to work. So your suggest will work in the normal case, but not in all cases.

Comment: The Text widget does not have a `selection_get` method.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Which version are you using? I am using Tkinter that ships with Python 2.7, and my text widgets definitely have a `selection_get`. (I just tried again in a console section just to be sure and it worked).

Comment: I should have been more precise: the text widget itself does not have a `selection_get` method. `selection_get` is a generic widget method available to all widgets. It does _not_  get the selected string from a text widget. It might, but it's not guaranteed. What it does is get what's called the "X"  selection (from tk's X11 roots). If you set `exportselection` to False for the text widget, `selection_get` will fail to work. So your suggest will work in the normal case, but not in all cases.

Answer (score 15):

The Text widget has a special tag named 'sel', accessible via Tkinter.SEL and testable via text_widget.tag_ranges(Tkinter.SEL), which allows you to retrieve the "selected" text. Here is a simple example:

```
if textWidget.tag_ranges(Tkinter.SEL):
    print('SELECTED Text is %r' % textWidget.get(Tkinter.SEL_FIRST, Tkinter.SEL_LAST))
else:
    print('NO Selected Text')
```

If you want a slightly more advanced solution, you can also try:

```
ranges = textWidget.tag_ranges(Tkinter.SEL)
if ranges:
    print('SELECTED Text is %r' % textWidget.get(*ranges))
else:
    print('NO Selected Text')
```

Comment: Plus1 for checking if there is any selected text to begin with. Otherwise SEL_FIRST/LAST will error :-)

Answer (score 9):

use the `get` method. If you want the selected text use the indices `SEL_FIRST` and `SEL_LAST`.

[edit]] one of the comments speculated this didn't work with Tkinter because there was no attribute "sel". "sel" isn't an attribute, it's a tag.  Tags are a remarkably powerful feature of the text widget.

Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        root=tk.Tk()
        self.text = tk.Text(root)
        self.text.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(root, text="Get Selection", command=self.OnButton)
        self.button.pack()
        root.mainloop()

    def OnButton(self):
        print "selected text: '%s'" % self.text.get(tk.SEL_FIRST, tk.SEL_LAST)


app=App()
```

For this demo to work, type some text in the text box then press the button.

Comment: I see no such "sel" attribute in Text or Entry widgets -- maybe you are refering to methods avaliable from TCL, but that are wrapped under other name in Python?

Comment: @jsbueno: `sel` isn't an attribute. It's a text tag that represents the selection, and it is available under Tkinter.

Comment: There's no need to use the underlying string defined by Tk. `Tkinter` has a variable defined for accessing it - `SEL_FIRST` and `SEL_LAST`.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: I don't like your edit very much. While you say there's no reason to use the underlying string because there's a variable, I say there's no need to use a variable for something that has a constant string representation.

Comment: @BryanOakley The issue with using the strings from `Tk/Tcl` is that those may change in future versions. The string literal would work on some versions and not others. If you instead use the variable defined by `Tkinter` (each version of which is tightly bound to a specific version of `Tk/Tcl`), you're guaranteed that it will always work. Further, you shouldn't be mixing your `Python` code with `Tcl` anymore than necessary. If you don't use as much `Python` as possible, why draw the line where you have? Why not just write everything in `Tcl`?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: those strings are decades old and tcl takes backwards compatibility very seriously. There is no chance they will ever change. The advantage to using the strings is that the knowledge of using ".first", etc. can be transferred to all tags, not just the selection. Using the strings isn't "mixing python code with tcl" -- the strings are the documented interface.