# Tkinter Text Widget Keyword Colouring

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, syntax-highlighting

I was wondering if it was possible to color specific keywords within a Text widget in Tkinter. I am basically trying to make a programming text editor, so maybe the `if` statement would be one color and the `else` statement would be another. Thanks for reading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the color of certain words in the tinter text widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786507/how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-words-in-the-tkinter-text-widget)

Comment: click the link to get the answer

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately I think that this tutorial shows how to color pre-inserted words, not words that the user types in.

Comment: I also get the error 'highlight_pattern' does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to bind a function to a Key event that searches for matching strings and applies a tag to any matching strings that modifies that string's attributes. Here's an example, with comments:

```
from Tkinter import *

# dictionary to hold words and colors
highlightWords = {'if': 'green',
                  'else': 'red'
                  }

def highlighter(event):
    '''the highlight function, called when a Key-press event occurs'''
    for k,v in highlightWords.iteritems(): # iterate over dict
        startIndex = '1.0'
        while True:
            startIndex = text.search(k, startIndex, END) # search for occurence of k
            if startIndex:
                endIndex = text.index('%s+%dc' % (startIndex, (len(k)))) # find end of k
                text.tag_add(k, startIndex, endIndex) # add tag to k
                text.tag_config(k, foreground=v)      # and color it with v
                startIndex = endIndex # reset startIndex to continue searching
            else:
                break

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()

text.bind('<Key>', highlighter) # bind key event to highlighter()

root.mainloop()
```

Example adapted from [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/932512-how-highlight-text-tkinter-do-you-know-what-i-am-doing-wrong)

More on `Text` widget [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: Thanks, now it makes since

Comment: By any chance is it possible to add all integers to the highlight words? Or all words with parenthesis?

Comment: Do you mean adding 0-9 to the dictionary? If so, yes, that is possible. You can add whatever you want as a key, as long as it's in an acceptable format.

Comment: I mean the user will enter "what ever they want" and as long as it is in "", it will be colored.