# How merge text in a tkinter label with different colors

Tags: python, colors, tkinter, label

I'm coding a little stocks ticker displayer program with tkinter label and I need to merge in the same line text in red color and green color.  How can I do that?

If not, is there any other widget which I can do it with?

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "merge in the same line". It is possible to change Label colour, but I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Batman in a stock exchange ticket the symbols and prices of the securities are scrolling in a text lines, but each securitie is put in red or in green according with the daily changes of the price. Like this image: http://ak4.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/3670265/preview/stock-footage-custom-made-stock-ticker-symbols-and-prices-animated-across-the-screen-symbols-are-original-not.jpg

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Is there something wrong with the `Text.tag_config` method that you can't use it to set the `foreground` color of your desired text? If it's not working, show the code you've got.

Comment: A quick google and I found this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786507/how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-words-in-the-tkinter-text-widget). Does this help at all?

Comment: @Kevin I'm using a Label widget for display the ticker.  Has the Label widget the .tag_config method or anyone similar?

Comment: No, if you want to use the `tag_config` method, you should use the Text widget.

Comment: @Shadow9043 The Text widget is a bit puzzling for me, so I'm trying to do that with the Label widget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have multiple colors in a label. If you want multiple colors, use a one-line Text widget, or use a canvas with a text item.

Here's a quick and dirty example using a text widget. It doesn't do smooth scrolling, doesn't use any real data, and leaks memory since I never trim the text in the input widget, but it gives the general idea:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ticker = tk.Text(height=1, wrap="none")
        self.ticker.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.ticker.tag_configure("up", foreground="green")
        self.ticker.tag_configure("down", foreground="red")
        self.ticker.tag_configure("event", foreground="black")

        self.data = ["AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT"]
        self.after_idle(self.tick)

    def tick(self):
        symbol = self.data.pop(0)
        self.data.append(symbol) 

        n = random.randint(-1,1)
        tag = {-1: "down", 0: "even", 1: "up"}[n]

        self.ticker.configure(state="normal")
        self.ticker.insert("end", " %s %s" % (symbol, n), tag)
        self.ticker.see("end")
        self.ticker.configure(state="disabled")
        self.after(1000, self.tick)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank @BryanOakley, beautiful code!!  I'd learned the Text tags with only read it !  Now, I've to refactor my scrolling algorithm that is more complex (here is, my code: https://github.com/SalvaJ/Learning/blob/master/tk_tutorial/ticker_display.py).  You've helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to get two colours on the same line you can use several labels and use `.grid()` to get them on the same line.

If you know you wanted two words and two colours for example you can use something like this:

```
root = Tk()
Label(root,text="red text",fg="red").grid(column=0,row=0)
Label(root,text="green text",fg="green").grid(column=0,row=1)
mainloop()
```

Or if you wanted to have a different colours for each word in a string for example:

```
words = ["word1","word2","word3","word4"]
colours = ["blue","green","red","yellow"]

for index,word in enumerate(words):
    Label(window,text = word,fg=colours[index]).grid(column=index,row=0)
```