# Add label text with different color in tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tcltk

```
label .f -text "Serial Number" -textvariable lbl -font {bold} -background #808080 
pack .f
```

Here, I want `Serial` with different color than `Number` with different color.
How to do that?

Also, when I do :

```
set lbl "Stack Overflow is great"
```

I want all words in different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label widget can't do this on its own; *by design* it is extremely simple, and will only use one font and one colour for its text (at a time).

The usual way of dealing with this is to use a text widget instead (with all scrolling disabled). That can do much more complicated things.

```
text .t
.t insert end "Serial " -tag word1
.t insert end "Number: " -tag word2
.t tag configure word1 -foreground "#660000"
.t tag configure word2 -foreground cyan
```

The downside is that making text widgets respond to a variable as in your second example is a *lot* more work. For example, you'll need

- a variable write `trace` so that things actually respond to variable changes,
- to actually determine where the word boundaries are (in a way that means sense for your application),
- a concrete strategy for assigning colours to words
- some way to keep the whole thing under control (this isn't too bad if you're using a finite set of styles), and
- to control exactly the size of the text widget as its content size changes; this is very much not its normal mode of operation, which is more focused on being a scrollable editable hypertext widget.

Comment: That's not an exhaustive list, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first create a label of each word individually, and then pack them horizontally to get all the words in a different color. Also you can refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760910/how-merge-text-in-a-tkinter-label-with-different-colors#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=You%20cannot%20have%20multiple%20colors,canvas%20with%20a%20text%20item.)