# Tkinter Text Widget color certain text

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I have a `Text` widget that is uneditable where text can be added with an `Entry` widget. I would like certain text in the `Text` widget to be differently colored than the rest depending on the type of text that is sent in. 
For example a possible output depending on types could be:

```
*Line one text* (color: Black)
*Line two text* (color: Blue)
*Line three text* (color: Black)
```

From what I have discovered it seems that this is possible to do using the `tag_add` and `tag_configure` method that the `Text` widget has but I am unsure how to do this.

I have the following method that appends the text to the `Text` widget and the ability to change the color of the text:

```
def append_to_display(self, text, color=standard):
    self.display.configure(state=NORMAL)
    self.display.tag_configure("color", foreground=color)
    self.display.insert(END, text + "\n", "color")
    self.display.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

However if I change the color to 'green' it doesn't change it for just the sent in text, it changes it for all the text.

So how do I make it work for only the text sent in?

Also note that I am running Python 3.6.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the color of certain words in the tkinter text widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786507/how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-words-in-the-tkinter-text-widget)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a unique tag name for each color.

```
def append_to_display(self, text, color=standard):
    tag_name = "color-" + color
    self.display.tag_configure(tag_name, foreground=color)
    ...
    self.display.insert(END, text + "\n", tag_name)
    ...
```