# Displaying statements with colours and symbols using tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a GUI app using tkinter that prints messages to the user via the text widget.
The app checks if the paper size of a document is A4 or not (via a series of loops and functions) and then prints appropriate messages.

The code was written using Python (3.10) on PyCharm (Community Edition 2021.3.3). The modules used are: tkinter (8.6) and python-docx (0.8.11).

I tried to print a message that starts with a check mark written in green text colour when the paper size is A4. But the message did not print properly. The code used to print this is shown below.

I suspect that the text widget may not be recognise the symbol and colour codes used.
I would like to know how I can insert such statements in the text widget. Or if perhaps there is another tkinter widget that allows such implementations.

I have tried the solutions presented in this post: [Changing the colour of text automatically inserted into tkinter widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591967/changing-the-colour-of-text-automatically-inserted-into-tkinter-widget) But this was not suitable for my purpose.

```
output_display.insert(1.0, '\033[92m' + '\u2705', "All pages are A4." + '\033[0m')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those escape codes are only recognized by your terminal.  You can use "tags" to color portions of a text widget.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/change-the-color-of-certain-words-in-the-tkinter-text-widget/