# Changing individual lines to different colors in a customtkinter textbox

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, tkinter-entry, customtkinter

I'd like to be able to change the color of text based on what the text contains in a CTkTextbox.  I've been able to find something kind of similar in tkinter, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591967/changing-the-colour-of-text-automatically-inserted-into-tkinter-widget",  which does what I need but I am unable to get it to work in customkinter.  I've tried tags, but it seems that regardless of the tag I specify when I insert the line it uses the last color defined in the tag config.  Ignore the 0.0 in the insert, I actually want the last insert to be at the top of the list.

Any ideas?

```
import customtkinter

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # configure grid system
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(master=self, width=400, corner_radius=0)
        self.textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.textbox.configure("1", text_color="red")
        self.textbox.configure("2", text_color="blue")

        self.textbox.insert("0.0", "Text color is red\n", "1")
        self.textbox.insert("0.0", "Text color is blue\n", "2")

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want us to ignore the "0.0", then don't put it in. Also, the first character is "1.0" not "0.0". Tkinter will gracefully accept an invalid index, but it's best not to be in the habit of using an invalid index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `.configure()` is used to change options of the widget itself and it is not *tag* related.

`.tag_config()` should be used on *tag related options*, but the options for a tkinter `Text` widget should be used instead of customtkinter options:

```py
# use .tag_config() instead of .configure()
# and tkinter option "foreground" is used instead of customtkinter option "text_color"
self.textbox.tag_config("1", foreground="red")
self.textbox.tag_config("2", foreground="blue")
```

Result:

[image]