which font has more preference figlet, or label_widget? and why Fore.'color' is not working to my figlet text?
So I am using pyfiglet module to add style to my text as you know, that on using pyfiglet.figlet_format() we pass an argument for 'font' or can keep using it as default i.e., 'doom', so now I want this styled text to be added on Label widget I tried to set font = ('consolas') and it changed the style of figlet font but using other font like sans-serif, monospace ms, doesn't seem to work So is there a preference of chosing font by figlet module or actually I am forcibly converting the font style from my side?
code -
from tkinter import *
import pyfiglet

window = Tk()

space_text = pyfiglet.figlet_format('Space', font = 'doom') # font is set to 'doom'
space_label = Label(window, text = space_text, bg = window_bg, fg = 'YELLOW', font = ('consolas',20))            
                        # font style is now set to consolas now the figlet font style is 
                        # changed but not for other fonts like sans-serif, etc. but why?
space_label.pack()

window.mainloop()

and also using 'Fore' module to add color to my figlet font like:
label = (root, text = Fore.YELLOW + space_text) is not working I have to add fg exclusively
to change font color of figlet text so is there a problem with that?

Label in Tkinter can't use color codes in string. It may have only one color which you set with fg=. If you needs different colors then you need Text() and tags (not Fore) - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47592287/1832058

maybe some fonts use different names in tkinter. See python - List available font families in `tkinter` - Stack Overflow

It is better to show what the expected and current results are.

Note that Fore.YELLOW is ANSI color code which tkinter Label widget does not support.  It is the normal way to set text color of a Label widget via fg (or foreground) option.
