# Python 3 Tkinter | Change color/style for words in between ':' in Text Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, emoji, text-widget

Let's say we have this text:

```
text = "You don't need to try to find hidden meaning:\nin this text :sun_with_face:!\nthis text : does not have any :meaning :D"
```

Now notice the `:sun_with_face:` in the text above? That's what I am trying to get somehow highlighted by changing the boldness and the color of the Text Widget to that particular section.

Issue:

- How to filter the text for `:these_words:`? You may notice that those are `emoji.demojized()` emoji so an optional solution would be to highlight all words that are in the `emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI` list but I feel that it will tax on the resources and time a lot (since the list contains over 1000 items)
- How to highlight the wanted stuff. Even though we might somehow solve the first issue, these demojized emoji are in the middle of the text...

**Edit**

Just to clarify: I know how to highlight the text from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786507/how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-words-in-the-tkinter-text-widget). I just need to know the location of the word to high light it, which is the tricky part. Also the :sun_with_face:. It can be anything as long as its open and closed with ':' and in-between there are **no** spaces () and newlines (`\n`).

Comment: Just to clarify: you're asking how to search for `:sun_with_face:`, and apply a tag to it?

Comment: You say in-between the characters can only be a-z, but the example you give includes underscores.

Comment: @BryanOakley oh right....I just realize it can also have `-`, `&`...etc. forget that statement. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking is how to apply a highlight to text that begins with a colon, has some sort span of text, and ends with a colon. You can find text that matches that pattern with the text widget `search` method, and you can apply the highlighting by using the tag feature of text widgets.

Since you are wanting to search against a pattern, you need to use a regular expression search. You do this by setting `regexp` to `True` when you call the `search` method. Because the pattern can be any length, you also need to pass in a variable so that tkinter can return how many characters it matched. You can use this information to apply the highlighting.

Note: when using regular expression searches, the expression must follow the [Tcl regular expression syntax](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), not the python one. There are some subtle differences.

Here's an example that finds all matches of a colon followed immediately by the shortest group of non-whitespace characters, followed by a colon. It then adds the tag "highlight" to each match:

```
countVar = tk.IntVar()
start_index = "1.0"
while start_index:
    index = text_widget.search(r':\S+?:', start_index, stopindex="end",
                               count=countVar, regexp=True)
    if index:
        # ie: a match was found
        end_index = "{} + {} chars".format(index, countVar.get())
        text_widget.tag_add("highlight", index, end_index)
        start_index = end_index
    else:
        start_index = None
```

Comment: It worked pretty well, though I noticed that when there is this two of the to-be-highlighted text next to each other: `:European_Union::Poland:`, for some reason it highlights only the first one...

Comment: I don't think `+'+1c'` (plus one character to the end index) is necessary.

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner: you are correct. I've changed that, and also tweaked the pattern slightly.