# Tkinter: I can't highlight text in text widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I made a text editor using `tkinter` and I used  `tag_config` to highlight the syntax.

**CODE**

```
#Importing modules
from tkinter import *

#Main Window
Window = Tk()
Window.minsize(400, 550)

##Main Script
#Defs


#Main frame
main = Frame(Window)

#Main text widget
text = Text(main, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0, bg="#323232", fg="white")

#Configs
text.config(width=55, height=35)
main.config(width=55, height=35)

#Tag config for coloring syntax
text.tag_configure("import", foreground="yellow")
Window.update()

#Packs and places
#main.place(anchor="c", rely=.5, relx=.5)
main.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side="right")

text.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

#Update window
Window.update()

#Window.mainloop()
Window.mainloop()
```

**PROBLEM**
The `tag_configure` is not working in line 23
`text.tag_configure("import", foreground="yellow")`

**QUESTION**
Is there a way to fix that? or Is there any way to highlighting text in tkinter?

**EDIT**
I add

```
def check_syntax(event):
    text.tag_add('import', 1.0, END)       

text.bind("<Return>", check_syntax)
```

on the code but there are 1 problem, when i run the code and type
`import tkinter` in the text widget for test and press enter the "tkinter" is highlighted too
How to fix that?

Comment: Do you have to call use `tag_add(tagname, startindex[,endindex] ...)` also? And then `tag_delete(tagname)` or tag_remove(tagname, startindex[,endindex] ...)` to remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is that you need to actually add a tag first using the tag_add function. You should read this other question with a similar problem. I tried out the code myself and it works. (You'll have to press enter after completing a line)

[How to use tkinter tag_config? Python 3.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956809/how-to-use-tkinter-tag-config-python-3-7-3)

Answer (score 0):

`tag_configure` only *configures* a tag, it doesn't apply the tag to a range of text. To use the tag you need to call `tag_add` and give it a start and end index. That, or add the tag when calling `insert`.

For example, this shows how to insert some text, and then apply highlighting to a few characters:

```
text.insert("end", "import foo\nimport bar\n")
text.tag_add("import", "1.0", "1.6")
text.tag_add("import", "2.0", "2.6")
```