# How can I set some text color in a tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, text, colors

can someone tell me how can I change color to certain parts of a tkinter text widget.
This is a simple view of my code (it's a chat so it has to display who sent the message):

```
T = Text(window, bg="black", fg="white", font=("bold", 12))

def addMessage(text)
    T.insert("me: ")
    T.insert(text+"\n")

addMessage("hi")
```

how can I set the "me: " part to be blue and the text part to stay white?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-words-in-the-tkinter-text-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786507)

Comment: already seen, didn't understand much tho

Comment: ***already seen,***: Read up on [How do I ask a good question? - Section: Search, and research - including links to related questions that haven't helped](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The answer to your question can be found in standard documentation for the text widget, and there are countless examples on the internet. What specific problem are you having?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

T = Text(window, bg="black", fg="white", font=("bold", 12))
# Create a tag named "blue" and set the color of it to blue
T.tag_config("blue", foreground="blue")
T.grid()

def addMessage(text):
    # apply the tag while inserting
    T.insert(END, "me: ", "blue")
    T.insert(END, text+"\n")

addMessage("hi")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can simply pass the optional `tags` argument in `T.insert()`: `T.insert(END, "me: ", "blue")`.

Comment: @Beyram: how is adding `, "blue"` plus one additional line of code _complicated_? I don't think it's possible to make it any simpler.

Comment: yes but it isn't obvious, in java the gui is pretty simple and obvious, you put all the configurations in one place without creating any additional tag or something