# How Do I Replace A Word With Another one In tkinter.Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

I am actually trying to make a python coding editor, for that I need to make a color-coding system. For example: 'def', 'or', 'if', 'elif', 'else', 'import' etc. should be in different colors as they are commands. Something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

def colorcommands():
    while True:
        a = textArea.get(0.0, END)
        for f in ["def", "or", "and", "if", "import", "else"]:
            textArea.replace(f, (f, fg="red"))

master = Tk()

textArea = Text()
textArea.pack()

threading.Thread(target=colorcommands).start()

master.mainloop()
```

But obviously this gives me an error, as there is no such command as this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `0.0` is an invalid index for two reasons. The first character is `"1.0"`, and indexes should be strings. `0.0` works because tkinter will translate it to `"1.0"`, but using floating point numbers is technically incorrect.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The title says you want to replace the text but the body says you want to  highlight the text.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code and it works perfectly:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading, keyword

def Process():
    while True:
        a = textArea.get(0.0, END)
        b = a.split("\n")
        words = {}
        for f in range(1, len(b)+1):
            bb = b[f-1].split(" ")
            bb2 = []
            for ff in range(1, len(bb)+1):
                try:
                    bb3 = words[bb[ff-1]]
                    bb3.append(str(f) + "." + str(len(" ".join(bb2))) + " - " + str(f) + "." + str(len(" ".join(bb2)) + len(bb[ff-1]) + 1))
                except:
                    words[bb[ff-1]] = [str(f) + "." + str(len(" ".join(bb2))) + " - " + str(f) + "." + str(len(" ".join(bb2)) + len(bb[ff-1]) + 1)]
                bb2.append(bb[ff-1])

        for f3 in words:
            if f3 in keyword.kwlist:
                for ff in words[f3]:
                    wordss = ff.split(" - ")
                    textArea.tag_add("code", wordss[0], wordss[1])
                    textArea.tag_config("code", foreground="red")

master = Tk()

textArea = Text()
textArea.pack()

threading.Thread(target=Process).start()

master.mainloop()
```

Thank You Everyone! :D

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can accomplish this through the use of tags. Tags can be used to alter certain parts of Text in Tkinter. First up is actually configuring the tag with *tag_configure*, then applying it with *tag_add*. You'll have to look the details of the syntax yourself.

I found another answer by someone who had the same question. In the accepted answer, you can find an example code. Run that and see if it works for you. 
[How to change the color of certain words in the tkinter text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786507/how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-words-in-the-tkinter-text-widget)

Comment: this helped a lot :)