# How i can highlight some words in a tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

this is my first question here...
Im doing a project that highlight words entered in a  list
How i can highlight it?
my code:

```
   import tkinter
   root = tkinter.Tk()
   words = ["Potatos","Tomatoes","Carrots"]
   box = tkinter.Text(root)
   box.pack()
   root.mainloop()
```

How i can highlight the text of a color if i enter a word that is in the words list?
im sorry if i sound stupid but im a novice

Comment: here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786507/how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-words-in-the-tkinter-text-widget/30339009

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to highlight text in a tkinter Text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781670/how-to-highlight-text-in-a-tkinter-text-widget)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Add `highlight_text()` function.
- Add `clear()` function.
- Add `Button` for highlight.
- Add `Button` for clear.
- Remove brace bracket that you don't needed `List`

Modified code:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()

def highlight_text():
    try:
        box.tag_add("start", "sel.first", "sel.last")        
    except tk.TclError:
        pass

def clear():
    box.tag_remove("start",  "1.0", 'end')
       
words = "Potatos","Tomatoes","Carrots"
        
box = tkinter.Text(root, width=25, height=5)
box.insert(tkinter.INSERT, words)
box.pack()
box.tag_configure("start", background="black", foreground="red")

highlight_btn = tkinter.Button(root, text="Highlight", command=highlight_text)
highlight_btn.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
       
clear_btn = tkinter.Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear)
clear_btn.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Output before,                           highlight and clear:

[image]  [image]   [image]