# How to get the start and end index of the selection in a Tkinter entry widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, selection, tkinter-entry

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073468/how-do-i-get-a-selected-string-in-from-a-tkinter-text-box) asks about getting the text selected but I was wondering how you can get the indexes of the start and end of the selection. Effbot mentions `ANCHOR` [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) but not the method in which you would use it. `get` and `selection_get` don't take any additional arguments so I don't know how to use it. I can't use the position of the cursor and length of selection because it could be on either side of the cursor and I can't use the `index` method since there could be multiple instances. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `index` method to return the index of the beginning and end of the selection with the index `"sel.first"` and `"sel.last"`.

```
entry=tk.Entry(...)
...
selection = (entry.index("sel.first"), entry.index("sel.last"))
```

Note: `"sel.last"` refers to the character just *after* the selection. Also, these indexes will cause an error to be thrown if used when there is nothing selected.