Is there a way to capture Event from focused Text widget before it gets to widget
QUESTION:
Is there a better way to do this?  Can I hijack the Event before it reaches the focused Text widget?  Or is emulating the behavior I want the best I can do?
PROBLEM:
Using Python 2.7 Tkinter.  I have a scrollable Text widget in one Frame and scrollable Canvas in another Frame.
I have enabled text selection in the Text widget, but not typing.  The Text widget scrolls just fine if text is selected (Text widget is focused) or if other widgets are focused.
Problem is when text is selected, the Text widget has focus, and grabs <MouseWheel> events and applies the Event to the Text widget in addition to the Canvas widget that is supposed to be scrolled.  The Event grabbing by focused widgets is inherent behavior to Python 2.
(Note for brevity the following code snippets do not include standard Tkinter code such as gridding the widgets as that is not part of the question.)
<-- SNIP -->
import Tkinter as tk

class MouseWheelConf:

    # Note passing the widget and the scrollbar to these routines
    # is to allow use of this convenience class for both widgets

    def _on_mouse_wheel(self, event, widget, scrollbar):
        #### Scroll the provided widget & scrollbar using Mousewheel event ####

    def _bind_mouse_wheel(self, event, widget, scrollbar):
        # Bind scrolling to Mousewheel event:
        self.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', 
                      lambda e: self._on_mouse_wheel(e, widget, scrollbar))

    def _unbind_mouse_wheel(self):
        # Unbind scrolling from Mousewheel event:
        self.unbind_all('<MouseWheel>')

class ScrollableText(MouseWheelConf):
    def __init__(self, master=None, text_conf={}, frame_conf={}):
        # Initialize scrolling Text frame:
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **frame_conf)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, **text_conf)

        # Set up scrolling:
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(
            self, orient='vertical', 
            command=lambda *e: self.text.yview(*e))
        self.scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.text.config(yscrollcommand=lambda *e: self.scrollbar.set(*e))

        # Apply scroll on enter and remove it when leave:
        self.bind(
            '<Enter>', 
            lambda e: self._bind_mouse_wheel(e, self.text, self.scrollbar))
        self.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: self._unbind_mouse_wheel(e))

        #### Grid all widgets here ####


class ScrollableCanvas(MouseWheelConf):
    def __init__(self, master=None, canvas_conf={}, frame_conf={}, canvasframe_conf={}):
        #### Standard scrolling canvas code goes here ####


<-- SNIP -->
Note: Python 3 does not have this issue but this code does work in Python 3.
WORKAROUND:
Current workaround is to add a copy of the sel tag (sel_copy) to apply to selected text extents on <FocusOut> of Text widget, and then when <<Leave>> the Text widget, apply focus to the Text widget master (Frame) and immediately apply the sel_copy tag to the selected text (losing the selected text extents).
<-- SNIP -->
class MouseWheelConf:
    #### PRIOR CODE GOES HERE ####

    # Only change is to unbind method:
    def _unbind_mouse_wheel(self, event, widget):
        #### PRIOR CODE GOES HERE ####
        
        # Change focus to Text master on Leave event:
        if 'text' in widget._name:
            # If Text is focused on Leave, change focus to Frame (master)
            # (this removes 'sel' tag from Text widget!)
            if self.focus_get() == widget:
                widget.master.focus()

class ScrollableText(MouseWheelConf):
    def __init__(self, master=None, text_conf={}, frame_conf={}):
        #### PRIOR CODE GOES HERE ####

        # Change the Leave binding to include the widget:
        self.bind(
            '<Leave>', 
            lambda e: self._unbind_mouse_wheel(e, self.text))

        # Workaround:
        self._create_sel_copy()
        self.text.bind(
            '<FocusOut>', lambda e: self._apply_sel_copy(self.text, e))
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda e: self._remove_sel_copy(self.text, e))
        self.text.bind(
            '<FocusIn>', lambda e: self._remove_sel_copy(self.text, e))

    def _create_sel_copy(self):
        #### Create copy of sel tag named 'sel_copy' here ####

    def _apply_sel_copy(self, widget, *event):
        # Apply sel tag copy copy when sel removed:
        if widget.tag_ranges("sel"):
            widget.tag_add("sel_copy", *widget.tag_ranges("sel"))

    def _remove_sel_copy(self, widget, *event):
        # Remove sel tag copy manually:
        widget.tag_remove("sel_copy", '1.0', 'end')


<-- SNIP -->

If you want to keep the selection, try setting exportselection=0 when creating the text widget.

My understanding is exportselection doesn't keep the tag applied it just sends the selected text to the selection_get() method which just allows the selected text to be sent to another widget or printed.  However, whether exportselection is 1 or 0 the 'sel' tag extents are still available for the moment after they are removed which is how I can apply a new tag to the text immediately after moving focus (which removes the selection). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073468/how-do-i-get-a-selected-string-in-from-a-tkinter-text-box
